# Is there a Dreamweaver plugin for proper SASS syntax highlighting / color coding?

Tags: sass, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS4 and have only started using SASS for my workflow. My only problem is when I code on style.scss, using SASS syntax, Dreamweaver colors / highlights the syntax like normal CSS, hence, I find it a bit confusing or as if something is wrong.

**Example:**

[image]

It just looks untidy and inconsistent. So, is there a Dreamweaver plug-in that will change the color-coding / highlighting to be SASS-based (so to speak)?

Comment: i use aptana as code editor, and i'm happy with that. this also has Sass highlighting, but i think its possible to add the sass highlighting in dreamweaver too.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic for SO.